# ruby rails: ArgumentError in index: key must be 32 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just a newbie in Rails.
I'm following the tutorial on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and I got this issue:
I created a controller running
`rails generate controller Welcome index`, then added `get 'welcome/index'`  and `root 'welcome#index'` to `config/routes.rb`.
Opening `localhost:3000` (default for ruby server) gives me this [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXkGQ.png)

I did a bit of research here on StackOverflow and GitHub, where I found that the issue could be solved by linking the rails 5-0-stable version on github in gemfile, but bundle install couldn't find the git file. I also tried changing config/routes.rb, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.
I read some answers talking about changing the call in the source file, but I coldn't understand which file they were talking about (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25448)

ruby and rails version: 
`ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]` 
`Rails 4.2.6`

PS: I don't think it's got anything to do with this, but I had some problems starting the server because bundle install gave `error: couldn't build native extensions`, which I solved installing ruby-dev via apt and some gems individually via `gem install`.

**Edit:**

Commands run from terminal:

```
$ rails new blog
$ cd blog
$ rails server
```

Files edited:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'layout/application'
end
```

Thanks for your help!

After trying to link github ruby 5.2:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching https://github.com/rails/rails.git
sh: 1: git: not found
Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git' "~/.bundle/cache/git/rails-fcf0202857b07db1a0f6220dae5ca99319ca0f32" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git' "~/.bundle/cache/git/rails-fcf0202857b07db1a0f6220dae5ca99319ca0f32" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory ~/script/ruby/blog has failed.sh: 1: git: not found
Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'
"~/.bundle/cache/git/rails-fcf0202857b07db1a0f6220dae5ca99319ca0f32" --bare
--no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory ~/script/ruby/blog has failed.
```

Comment: if you need some more information I'll be glad to provide it

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stackoverflow. The current question is not the way it is expected to be, so read [ask] to have overall information and also [mcve] to know what information are expected to be provided, so you can [edit] your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just started a new Rails application ? If so you should go straight to Rails 5.2 which seems to be the latest stable version at the time of writing.

At the top of my Gemfile generated by `rails s` I have the following

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Rails
gem 'rails', github: "rails/rails", branch: "5-2-stable"
```

Try to change your Gemfile with this and re-run `bundle`

Also, in order to manage your ruby versions, I highly suggest you switch to [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) rather than have your system manage Ruby versions